"A set of Guatemalas" in Forster's Maurice?
What does Forster mean by a "set of Guatemalas"? (From Chapter 1 of Maurice.)

"Well, Hall, expecting a pi-jaw, eh?"
"I don't know, sir—Mr Abrahams' given me one with 'Those Holy Fields'. Mrs Abrahams' given me sleeve-links. The fellows have given me a set of Guatemalas up to two dollars. Look, sir! The ones with the parrot on the pillar on."


But what is a pi-jaw?

@AntonSherwood https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pi-jaw

Maurice collects stamps, and the "set of Guatemalas" refers to a set of Guatemalan stamps of different denominations. We are indeed told subsequently, that at home "His Guatemala stamps were admired". The phrase "The parrot on the pillar" refers to  a characteristic image used on such stamps, that of a quetzal - a national emblem of Guatemala, which Maurice misidentifies as a parrot - sitting on a pillar.

